# How to create UIImageView with image from a link?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, uiimageview, uiimage

How to create UIImageView with image from a link  like this http://img.abc.com/noPhoto4530.gif?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.abc.com/noPhoto4530.gif"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: Works perfect! Cannot imagin that "dataWithContentsOfURL" is in its static method. I'm using Xamarin by the way.

Comment: Can i timeout imageview ? when internet connection is slow application can be crashed so i wants to add timeout @nszombie

Comment: You should note that this is not a great solution because it blocks the main thread waiting for the download. An async loading approach for the data is much better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download the picture in the background, and then set it on the main thread, you can do it like this:

```
- (void)downloadPicture {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.abc.com/noPhoto4530.gif"];

                UIImage *image = [self getPicture:url];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self setPicture:image];

                });
            });
}

 - (UIImage *)getPicture:(NSURL *)pictureURL {

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        return image;    
}

 - (void)setPicture:(UIImage *)image {

        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                               CGRectMake(kPictureX, kPictureY, image.size.height, image.size.width)];

        [imageView setImage:image];

        [self.view addSubview: imageView];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet for those looking to use iOS 7's new suite of NSURLSession classes:

```
// Set NSURLSessionConfig to be a default session
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

// Create session using config
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

// Create URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"];

// Create URL request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

// Create data task
NSURLSessionDataTask *getDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // Okay, now we have the image data (on a background thread)
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    // We want to update our UI so we switch to the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Create image view using fetched image (or update an existing one)
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        // Do whatever other UI updates are needed here on the main thread...
    });
}];

// Execute request
[getDataTask resume];
```

Comment: The accepted answer is quite old and bad practice anyway.  This is the correct answer (with proper error handling of course ;)).

Answer (score 1):

Download image to a local path on your device then get a UIImage from `imageWithContentsOfFile` and use this to set the image in the `UIImageView`. Remember to cleanup your image file sometime.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the image you need also to place it as a subview from a view, like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.abc.com/noPhoto4530.gif"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[someOtherView addSubview:myImageView];
[myImageView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510223/xcode-iphone-programming-loading-a-jpg-into-a-uiimageview-from-url), or you can use NSURLConnection to download the image data and create the UIImage to set to you UIImageView.  I personally prefer using NSURLConnection to download the image asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer can have here

```
NSURL *urlLink = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.abc.com/noPhoto4530.gif"];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlLink];
UIImage *imageData = [UIImage imageWithData:dataURL];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try modern gcd style (xcode 8.0+):

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.mydomain.queue3")
queue.async {
    let imageURL: URL = URL(string: "https://www.brightedge.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Google-Secure-Search_SEL.jpg")!
    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL) else {
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

you can also replace the first `DispatchQueue` with `URLSession.dataTask`

```
let imageURL: URL = URL(string: "https://www.brightedge.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Google-Secure-Search_SEL.jpg")!

(URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)).dataTask(with: imageURL, completionHandler: { (imageData, response, error) in

    if let data = imageData {
        print("Did download image data")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}).resume()
```