# ScrollView with over 150 images crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, uiscrollview, crash

I've an application which is a scrollView filled with over 150 images .. I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content%27) to create it .. the application is over 550MBs and it has about 500 (150 for iPhone 5 & 150 for Retina & 150 for non-retina & buttons) photos .. The application runs very well on the simulator with no problems but on a real device when I open the application it keeps loading then a crash

so can anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you debug on device. What exactly was the error?

Comment: This crash might be due to memory constraints.

Comment: I get no errors there is any programatic bugs or any thing related to this .. I think it crashes because the scrollView is overloaded with images .. BTW I've tried to make them 80 only and the application worked on my device very well.

Comment: Of course the app does not crash on the Simulator because it has the access to all your Mac's RAM

Comment: @AppleDelegate yes, I think so .. do you know any fix for this ?

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Yup, you are right.

Comment: @user1766119 Just make sure you implement the lazy loading right. It seems like you load all the images at once

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu I think you're right, can you please check the tutorial if it has lazy loading (sorry I'm beginner) ... I've exactly followed the tutorial .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load only those images needed for displaying. ie while scrolling those images that are hidden should be taken off from the scrollview. Maybe you can make a design similar to the working of reusable UITableViewCell. ie a custom implementation for showing only the needed images and reusing them while scrolling.

There is another way, not a straight forward one, you can use a UITableView and add images to each cell and then rotate the tableview so that it will look like an horizontal scroll. 
The advantage of doing this method is that the UITableView will handle all the reusability issue and we dont need to worry about. But I am not sure whether its the right way to do this.

Btw.. I have uploaded an app with the UITableView rotated horizontal scroll view to the appstore without getting rejected ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer man, But I recommend using ScrollView with Paging .. I think the tutorial which I've mentioned in the questions shows off this (lazy loading) just command+f in the tutorial page .. but I just can't understand what they mean should I edit the number of the pages being displayed .. please see the tutorial and tell me. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: ah.. lazy loading is implemented in that tutorial. did you follow the tutorial till the end? they are using lazy loading to limit the number of images loaded.. i think following their tut is enough

Comment: Thank you for replying @xCode .. Yes, I've exactly followed the tutorial but I think there's a number in the code I should edit is that right ? `// Work out which pages you want to load
    NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
    NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;` 
I've tried to edit this but it views the number of pages I've edited only and other pages are black ? any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an good way to do that ,u can upload your photo on server side and when open the app. loading the image from server.

```
id path = @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Sholay-Main_Male_Cast.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

imageView.image = img;
```

LooK at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510223/xcode-iphone-programming-loading-a-jpg-into-a-uiimageview-from-url)

Comment: That means the user will need internet connection .. and that's not recommended for the type of my app :( is there is no any other ways to fix this ?

Comment: @user1766119 what u do not acceptable.for many reasons it will be crash if not reject by apple. the best way to do that is loading from server.
Give one app do what you want to do ???

Comment: What about lazy loading ? can you give me any good tutorial for this and I will accept your answer immediately ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083454/objective-c-custom-lazy-load-images-uitableview-cell

Comment: Oh, thank you so much .. but one more thing please .. can you check the tutorial in my question if it has lazy loading (I've exactly followed this tutorial).

Comment: I swear it is not me .. I've just accepted your answer .. anyway I will vote up :) please check it now :)

Comment: Here you are :- http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content%27

Comment: actually the problem didn't solved yet , I asked you to check lazy loading in the tutorial but you din't answer :) anyway I voted up your answer and I will accept it if you replied .. thank you :)