# show image in uiimageview through json string url

Tags: objective-c

```
for (NSDictionary *result in results) {

    NSString *name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *images=[result objectForKey:@"img"];

    NSLog(@"%@", name);

    NSLog(@"%@",images);

    displayApiLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name];
    NSData *convertData=[images dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",convertData);
    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:convertData];

    NSLog(@"sads%@",img);
}
```

i have a problem to show image and name in ios through json url string is there any one help me to resolve it Thanks in Advance

json return

```
{"DATA":[
    {"id":"1","name":"Fast Food","img":"http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410258775_58_fast-food.png"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Chinese","img":"http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410259648_28_chinees.png"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Drinks","img":"http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410259679_67_drinks.png"},
    {"id":"4","name":"Icecream","img":"http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410259705_34_icecream.png"},
    {"id":"5","name":"Continental","img":"http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410259737_53_master_icon.png"},
    {"id":"6","name":"Starter","img":"http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410592310_18_starter.png"}
 ],
"STATUS":{"X_STATUS_REQUEST":1,"X_STATUS_ERROR_CODE":0,"X_STATUS_ERROR_DESC":""}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode iPhone Programming: Loading a jpg into a UIImageView from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510223/xcode-iphone-programming-loading-a-jpg-into-a-uiimageview-from-url)

Comment: Try: NSDictionary *res = [result objectForKey:@"DATA"]; and then:
NSString *name = [res objectForKey@"name"];

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
NSDictionary *finalres = [result objectForKey:@"DATA"];

for (NSDictionary * finalres in results) {

    NSString *name = [finalres objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *images=[finalres objectForKey:@"img"];

    NSLog(@"%@", name);

    NSLog(@"%@",images);

    displayApiLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name];
    NSData *convertData=[images dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",convertData);
    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:convertData];

    NSLog(@"sads%@",img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2015-01-19 17:22:07.571 smartwok[1342:60b] Connection Successful

2015-01-19 17:22:07.664 smartwok[1342:60b] didReceiveResponse

2015-01-19 17:22:07.664 smartwok[1342:60b] connectionDidFinishLoading

2015-01-19 17:22:07.665 smartwok[1342:60b] Succeeded! Received 943 bytes of data

2015-01-19 17:22:07.665 smartwok[1342:60b] Fast Food

2015-01-19 17:22:07.665 smartwok[1342:60b] http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.131%2Fcafe_management%2Fmenu%2Fimages%2Fmaster_category%2F1410258775_58_fast-food.png

2015-01-19 17:22:07.666 smartwok[1342:60b] <68747470 3a2f2f31 302e302e 302e3133 312f6361 66655f6d 616e6167 656d656e 742f6d65 6e752f69 6d616765 732f6d61 73746572 5f636174 65676f72 792f3134 31303235 38373735 5f35385f 66617374 2d666f6f 642e706e 67>

2015-01-19 17:22:07.709 smartwok[1342:60b] sads(null)

it is not working